# Want to perform 'OR' query in mongodb driver class

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

My code performs 'AND' query but i want to perform OR query , but unable to figure out , how to do that. Below is my code for 'AND' query. The $match performs 'AND' query. Thank you in advance

```
<?php

$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'master_admin',
    'pipeline'  => [
        [
            '$match' =>
                ['full_name' => 'gg', 'username' => 'gg'],
        ],
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Can you please provide us how should be it using raw mongo shell query?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the official documentation it would go something like

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'master_admin',
    'pipeline'  => [
        [
            '$match' => [
                '$or' => [
                           ['full_name' => ['$eq' => 'gg']], 
                           ['username' => ['$eq' => 'gg']]
                ],
             ],
        ],
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);
```

I Haven't tested it out, but should work something along those lines. With the help of the documentation you should be able to make it work to your wishes.

Comment: Type: ParseErrorMessage: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']' at 'or'

Comment: I added the missing brackets, can you try now @ManuNarang

Comment: @ManuNarang When an answer is helpful you can upvote it and if it solved your problem, click the checkmark icon so future visitors know it solved the problem you posted